# MPMediaPickerController shows white screen , no error

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaplayercontroller

I get a white screen when I try to present `MPMediaPickerController`. After that, it automatically dismisses itself. I can't access music library in order to import songs in my app.
What is really weird is that there is no error printed out in the console.
I am testing on a physical iPhone device.

```
  @IBAction func importSong(_ sender: Any) {


    let mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController = MPMediaPickerController.self(mediaTypes: MPMediaType.music)
    mediaPicker.delegate = self
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
    self.present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

See video : https://youtu.be/8fjeWXjObPo

Comment: Have you set `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` key in your Info.plist file?

Comment: That's exactly what I had forgotten to set. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` in your Info.plist file, e.g.:

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>App wants to use music</string>
```